# Docker command to remove all the containers and their images except the ones with a particular label

Tags: docker

for example, 
If I have few containers with x and y labels

docker ps -a -q -f label=name=x

docker ps -a -q -f label=name=y

I want to keep them and delete all the remaining containers and their images from the system. What is the docker command???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use **comm**(1) to get the differences between the first command that lists all images and the second that filters by label, and pipe all that information to docker rmi/rm.  The sed command is used to remove the `<none>` string of untagged images, or images built with older versions of Docker.

For images:

```
comm -3 <(docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' | sort) <(docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' -f label=FOO=BAR | sort) | sed -rne 's/([^>]):<none>@/\1@/p' | xargs -r docker rmi
```

For containers:

```
comm -3 <(docker ps -a --format '{{.ID}}' | sort) <(docker ps -a --format '{{.ID}}' -f label=FOO=BAR | sort) | xargs -r docker rm
```

NOTE: Consider whether to add `-v` to the `docker rm` above to remove the associated volumes as well.

Comment: That was very helpful. What if I am having more than labels there? Do you have a solution? 

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Well, it depends on the case.  If there are a lot of labels, it would be easier to run it in a for loop.  Then there's the case for statuses `-f status=dead`.  There are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to accomplish this. Here is one simple way:

Just deleting the containers:

```
docker ps -a | grep -v 'java' | grep -v 'sql' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm

docker ps -a     => list all containers
grep -v 'java'   => anything that does not start with the name 'java'
grep -v 'sql'    => anything that does not start with the name 'sql'
...(add more here as required)
awk '{print $1}' => get the container id (i.e. first column from output)
xargs docker rm  => remove the matched containers
```

To delete the containers and corresponding images(just stop the containers and do a docker force remove image)

```
docker ps -a | grep -v 'java' | grep -v 'sql' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
docker ps -a | grep -v 'java' | grep -v 'sql' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Comment: Well! At this time I am only able to filter with label not name